# Помогите разобраться с REST запросом. Непонятная переменная

Tags: java, rest

Есть тело следующего POST запроса на создание юзера:

```
{
  "affiliateId": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "externalAuthToken": "string",
  "externalAuthType": "string",
  "fast": true,
  "firstName": "string",
  "grantType": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "meta": {},
  "password": "string",
  "rememberMe": true,
  "timezone": "string"
}
```

Работаю на JAVA. При создании класса с помощью "generate POJOs from JSON" создаёт класс "User" с полем "Меtа" И пустой класс "Meta". выполняю отправку следующим образом:

```
Response r = given().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).  
                body(user).                     
                post(url);
```

при получении ответа из r.statusCode() получаю 401. Вопроса два:
Что это может быть за мета? и вообще в чём тогда может быть причина ?
Спасибо!

Comment: тут используется какая-то библиотека сериализации json?

Comment: почитайте про http код 401 - у вас проблема с аутентификацией \ авторизацией.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, дело в том, что в Swagger тело пут запроса (JSON) содержало не все поля, я дописал необходимые поля (Идея сама красненьким в ответе сервера написала каких не хватает) и все заработало - код 200. Теперь другая проблема: тело которое приходит с сервера не содержит данные о пользователе (имя, фамилия т.д.) - все поля NULL. Остался только емеил. Как можно решить проблемe?  Спасибо!